# C program to count highest repetition of a number in an array of numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I write this code to count and print highest repetition of a number in an array of 10 numbers. The problem is this program don't do `counter++` while the number is same as the last number in array.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 9

int main () {
    float Student[SIZE],grade,maxValue;
    int i,j,k,slot,counter=0,maxCount=-1;
    printf("Enter the grade of 10 students \n");
    for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++){
        printf("Enter student %d grade : ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&Student[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<=SIZE;j++){
        grade = Student[j];
        counter = 0;    
        for(k=0;k<=SIZE;k++){
            if(k == j){
                continue;
            }
            if (grade == Student[k]){
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter > maxCount) {
                maxCount = counter;
                maxValue = grade;
            }

        }
    }

    if(maxCount == 0 ){
        printf("There are no duplicate numbers.\n");
    }else{
        printf("%.2f repeated %d times.\n",maxValue,maxCount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior: `for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++){` goes out of bounds on the array. -> `i < SIZE`.

Comment: Perhaps learning to use a debugger would help

Comment: @Unimportant SIZE is 9 array size is exactly 9. Tested and same result. Doesnt count if the number equals to last number

Comment: @EdHeal Im not pro at C, How to use and what debugger to use?

Comment: Depends on the IDE you are using

Comment: @AriaFathi - Since `SIZE` is 9, the valid indexes into the array are `0, 1, 2, ..., 7, 8`. Referencing `Student[9]` results in undefined behavior. The recommended paradigm for walking a C array is `for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ still same result

Comment: @EdHeal DevC++ im using it right now , but I usually user Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still there is a bug, as Your question says, You have 10 numbers and SIZE is still set to 9. The below code is working fine. It is almost similar to your code but with some difference that you should notice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main () {
    float Student[SIZE],grade,maxValue;
    int i,j,k,slot,counter=1,maxCount=1;
    printf("Enter the grade of 10 students \n");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("Enter student %d grade : ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&Student[i]);
    }
    for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++){
        grade = Student[j];
        counter = 1;
        for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++){
         if (grade == Student[k] && j!=k) {
                counter++;
         }
            if (counter > maxCount) {
                maxCount = counter;
                maxValue = grade;
            }

        }
    }

    if(maxCount == 1 ){
        printf("There are no duplicate numbers.\n");
    }else{
        printf("%.2f repeated %d times.\n",maxValue,maxCount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I and j are initialized from 0 and condition will be checked till size-1. So, change the condition from `j<=SIZE` to `j<SIZE` in both the loops.

Comment: Size is defined 9 ,User will enter 10 numbers , so I do this , it will go from 0 to 8.

Comment: And 0 to 8, including 0 itself, is ... 9 elements.

Comment: @Unimportant Can you give me full code to test? im testing it in anyway I can but same result every time

Comment: @AriaFathi: There are **three** loops - not 2 - which use `<= SIZE`. Do you really need your entire source repeated and with only these changes?

Comment: @AriaFathi - Try this http://ideone.com/51NJC0

Comment: @RadLexus Dude I tested it but always same result.

Comment: @Robᵩ Same result.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it my self , I added this code to the `if(k==j)` :

```
if(Student[9]){
counter++;
}
```

and after that goes `continue;`

Comment: No, just no..., back to undefined behavior. Simply remove the `if(k == j){ continue; }` completely. Each number should be allowed to positively compare with itself.